# Css sticky to bottom of page?

Tags: css

I have a fullscreen section that is sometimes, bigger that the screen. I want to use css Sticky to get it to align and stick the bottom of the section to the bottom of the viewport/window.

Sticking to the top like this works:

```css
body{
   height: 400vh;
}

section{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <section />
</body>
```

But I can't seem to stick to the bottom:

```css
body{
   height: 400vh;
}

section{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 150vh;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <section />
</body>
```

I also tried 
`bottom: -100vh;`

The height of section is dynamic.

Comment: If it is the only element on your page and it is bigger than the viewport, there is no way to have the bottom stick to the bottom of the screen, unless you have the page automatically scroll down

Comment: how do you mean automatically scrolls down?

Comment: you could either do `body { overflow-y:hidden; }` or use [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) whenever `<section>` gets larger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is in fact working, just that it is not as expected.

See below: (Added dummy `p` elements to demonstrate that it is working.)

```css
body{
   height: 400vh;
}

section{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 150vh;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <section />
</body>
```

The reason it looks like it isn't working is because `sticky` is a toggle between `fixed` and `relative` ([according to w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)), or, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), positions element relative to its flow root and containing block.

**What does it means?**

When the sticky element is placed at the top-most visible area in the containing block, according to the normal flow (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for more details), it is already visible in the containing block. So by definition it should not be "sticked" to the bottom.

```css
#sticky {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<div id="sticky">Sticky</div>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
```

However, when the sticky element is not placed at the top-most visible area, according to its normal flow, it is "hidden" and is either at the middle or at the end of the document. Therefore, by definition, it should be "sticked" to the bottom until you scroll past its original flow position.

```css
#sticky {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<div id="sticky">Sticky</div>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
<p>Not sticky</p>
```

Hope this explains the situation.